# How to set crop parameters to original image in React?

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, css, ecmascript-6

I am trying to crop an image before uploading it through an API. I am showing a modal ([`Dialog`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog)) to do this, and using this library [react-image-crop](https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop) to achieve this.

Here is the code snippet:

```
showCropImageModal() {
    const actions = [
        <FlatButton
          label="Cancel"
          primary={true}
          onClick={this.handleCancel}
        />,
        <FlatButton
          label="Crop"
          primary={true}
          keyboardFocused={true}
          onClick={this.handleCropClose}
        />,
    ];
    
    if (this.state.showImageCropper) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog
                    title="Crop the image"
                    actions={actions}
                    modal={true}
                    open={this.state.showImageCropper}
                    autoScrollBodyContent={true}
                >
                    <ReactCrop
                        src={this.state.selectedImageURL} 
                        crop={this.state.crop}
                        onComplete={(crop, pixel) => {console.log(crop, pixel)}}
                        onChange={(crop) => { console.log(crop); this.setState({crop}); }}
                    />
                </Dialog>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

On "Crop" action I am handling it using the `handleCropClose` function:

```
handleCropClose(){
    let {selectedFile, crop} = this.state
    const croppedImg = this.getCroppedImg(selectedFile, crop.width, crop.height, crop.x, crop.y, 2);
    console.log(croppedImg)
    this.setState({showImageCropper: false})
}
```

And here is `getCroppedImg` code:

```
getCroppedImg(imgObj, newWidth, newHeight, startX, startY, ratio) {
    /* the parameters: - the image element - the new width - the new height - the x point we start taking pixels - the y point we start taking pixels - the ratio */
    // Set up canvas for thumbnail
    console.log(imgObj)
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.state.selectedImageURL;
    var tnCanvas = this.refs.canvas;
    tnCanvas.width = newWidth;
    tnCanvas.height = newHeight;
    tnCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight);
    return tnCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Now, I am not able to get the right preview or new image file object so that I could use that to show as preview in the modal there itself and than use the same to upload it. I am not even getting the right image ratio. Any help?

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Hey, sorry, I think this question is a bit unclear—rather than asking for "any help?", what are you looking for help with?

Comment: I think it was pretty clear as to what I want. Please have a look again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`react-image-crop` using percent for scaling, make sure to calculate. Also make sure while create new object image on the fly to render virtual dom.

Here, try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactCrop, { makeAspectCrop } from 'react-image-crop';
import { FlatButton, Dialog } from 'material-ui';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import sample from './sample.png';
import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    showImageCropper: false,
    selectedImageURL: sample,
    crop: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      // aspect: 16 / 9,
    },
    selectedFile: null,
    croppedImage: sample
  };

  showCropImageModal() {
    const actions = [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        primary={true}
        onClick={this.handleCancel}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Crop"
        primary={true}
        keyboardFocused={true}
        onClick={this.handleCropClose}
      />,
    ];

    if (this.state.showImageCropper) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Dialog
            title="Crop the image"
            actions={actions}
            modal={true}
            open={this.state.showImageCropper}
            autoScrollBodyContent={true}
          >
            <ReactCrop
              src={this.state.selectedImageURL}
              crop={this.state.crop}
              // onImageLoaded={this.onImageLoaded}
              onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
              onChange={this.onCropChange}
            />
          </Dialog>

        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  onCropComplete = (crop, pixels) => {
  }

  onCropChange = (crop) => {
    this.setState({ crop });
  }

  // onImageLoaded = (image) => {
  //   this.setState({
  //     crop: makeAspectCrop({
  //       x: 0,
  //       y: 0,
  //       // aspect: 10 / 4,
  //       // width: 50,
  //     }, image.naturalWidth / image.naturalHeight),
  //     image,
  //   });
  // }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ showImageCropper: false });
  }

  handleCropClose = () => {
    let { crop } = this.state;

    // console.log("selectedFile", selectedFile);
    // console.log("crop",crop);

    const croppedImg = this.getCroppedImg(this.refImageCrop, crop);
    this.setState({ showImageCropper: false, croppedImage: croppedImg })
  }

  getCroppedImg(srcImage,pixelCrop) {
    /* the parameters: - the image element - the new width - the new height - the x point we start taking pixels - the y point we start taking pixels - the ratio */
    // Set up canvas for thumbnail
    // console.log(imgObj);
    // let img = new Image();
    // img.src = this.state.selectedImageURL;
    // let tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // let tnCanvas = tempCanvas;
    // tnCanvas.width = newWidth;
    // tnCanvas.height = newHeight;
    // tnCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight);
    // return tnCanvas;

    let img = new Image();
    img.src = this.state.selectedImageURL;
    const targetX = srcImage.width * pixelCrop.x / 100;
    const targetY = srcImage.height * pixelCrop.y / 100;
    const targetWidth = srcImage.width * pixelCrop.width / 100;
    const targetHeight = srcImage.height * pixelCrop.height / 100;

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = targetWidth;
    canvas.height = targetHeight;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(
      img,
      targetX,
      targetY,
      targetWidth,
      targetHeight,
      0,
      0,
      targetWidth,
      targetHeight
    );

    return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ showImageCropper: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="App">
        { this.showCropImageModal() }
          <img src={this.state.selectedImageURL} style={{display: "none"}} ref={(img) => {this.refImageCrop = img}} alt="" />
          <img src={this.state.croppedImage} alt="" />
          <FlatButton
            label="Open popup"
            primary={true}
            onClick={this.handleOpen}
          />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution** :

First, use pixel coordinates: 
  - change : `onChange={(crop) => { console.log(crop); this.setState({crop}); }}`
  - to `onChange={(crop, pixelCrop) => { console.log(crop); this.setState({crop, pixelCrop}); }}`.

Use `this.state.pixelCrop` instead of `this.state.crop` for `getCroppedImg`.

Then, update `getCroppedImg` to fetch the image asynchronously using a Promise and crop it.

```
getCroppedImg(imgObj, newWidth, newHeight, startX, startY, ratio) {
    /* the parameters: - the image element - the new width - the new height - the x point we start taking pixels - the y point we start taking pixels - the ratio */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const img = new Image();

      img.onload = resolve;
      img.onerror = reject;
      img.src = this.state.selectedImageURL;
    }).then(img => {
      // Set up canvas for thumbnail
      var tnCanvas = this.refs.canvas;

      tnCanvas.width = newWidth;
      tnCanvas.height = newHeight;
      tnCanvas
        .getContext('2d')
        .drawImage(
          img,
          startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight,
          0, 0, newWidth, newHeight
        );

      return tnCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    });
}
```

**Explanation** :

You are missing parameters to `drawImage`. You are asking the canvas to draw the image at position `(startX, startY)` and scale it to `(newWidth, newHeight)`.

To crop the image you need [additional parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) :

> ```
> drawImage(
>     image,
>     sx, sy, sw, sh,
>     dx, dy, dw, dh
> );
> ```
>
> Where :
>
> [image: drawImage]

**Example** :

```js
const img = new Image()
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

img.src = 'https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/640/clsd/getty/991dda07ecb947f1834bf1aa89153cf6'

const newWidth = 200
const newHeight = 200

const startX = 200
const startY = 100

img.onload = () => {
    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
}


document.body.appendChild(canvas)
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

Comment: I tried your getCroppedImg but it is still not working, as it does crop something, but not what I need and in right dimension. Could you use the same method to check if that works?

Comment: I tried the code, and it seems like it is not cropping what I select as an image. The runnable code is not what I tried though, I tried the one which you mentioned in the solution, getCroppedImg function.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce your code exactly like it is, does it work if you use `imgObj` instead of `img`? Else could you provide the contents of `crop` so we can see if it is using the correct coordinate space?

Comment: height: 33.33333333333333
​
width: 57.272727272727266
​
x: 24.261363636363637
​
y: 25.333333333333332

Comment: height: 33.33333333333333
​
width: 57.272727272727266
​
x: 24.261363636363637
​
y: 25.333333333333332 here are the contents of crop.

Comment: Could you provide the image url or upload it? I would like to try to manually crop it to see if it's the right coordinates

Comment: Hi, I have attached the image, I want the GYM word out of it for example.

Comment: I updated the answer to convert the position to pixels from percentages, could you try it? The react-image-crop doc was a bit misleading. The region I get from your coordinates isn't the word GYM though

Comment: I tried, but now getting 'TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.[Learn More]'

Comment: Ok, so this time I update the crop function to fetch the image asynchronously and crop it. I also updated the `onChange` to use the pixel crop. The thing is that it now returns a `Promise`, is it fine for you?